# Force a generic type parameter to be a class type?

Tags: generics, swift

I'm trying to figure out a method for avoiding retain cycles when some references in the cycle are held in collections. My idea was to create a wrapper `struct`:

```
struct Weak<T> {
    unowned let value: T

    init(_ value: T) {
        self.value = value
    }
}
```

The issue here is that `unowned` and `weak` members have to be of a class type (`main.swift:3:17: 'unowned' cannot be applied to non-class type 'T'; consider adding a class bound`), but there's no reasonable superclass for me to require that `T` inherit from.

Is there any way to force `T` to be of a class type without inheriting from a specific other class?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

try:

```
struct Weak<T:AnyObject>
```

Comment: Yep, read the section on generics for the syntax of the generic definition.  Do a search in the iBook on AnyObject for more information on that protocol.